# A list of lists from string in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I need a method that makes a list from a string like following:

```
"( * 1 2 ( - 4 3 ) )" -> ["*", 1, 2, ["-", 4, 3]]
```

Is there any simple way to handle this problem?

Comment: Writing a Lisp interpreter?

Comment: Recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple built-in to call or one-liner trick you can use, but it's still entirely manageable.

First, you'll want to tokenize the input. Roughly speaking, that means separating it into units like `(`, `*`, and `123`. If your input is guaranteed to be space-separated, you can just use the `split` method, but if you need to handle input like `(* (+ 1 2) 3)`, it could be a bit harder.

```
>>> "( * 1 2 ( - 4 3 ) )".split()
['(', '*', '1', '2', '(', '-', '4', '3', ')', ')']
```

Now that you have a sequence of tokens, we can write a recursive parser. Go over the tokens one at a time.

- If you see a number, call `int` or `float` on it and return the result.
- If you see something that isn't a number or a parenthesis, just return it as a string.
- If you see an opening parenthesis, recursively parse objects from the token sequence and add them to a list until you see a closing parenthesis. Return the list.

Answer (score 3):

Some thing like this:

```
a = " ( * 1 2 ( - 4 35 ) ( + 100 ( / 1 2 ) ) ( + 100 200 ) )"

def p(s):
    r = []
    for x in s:
        if x == "(":
            r.append( p(s) )
        elif x == ")":
            return r
        else:
            r.append(x)
    return r

p(iter(a.split()))
```

the output is:

Out[23]:

```
[['*',
  '1',
  '2',
  ['-', '4', '35'],
  ['+', '100', ['/', '1', '2']],
  ['+', '100', '200']]]
```

You need add some code to convert string to number.

Answer (score 3):

use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing), like:

```
from pyparsing import *

enclosed = Forward()
nestedParens = nestedExpr('(', ')', content=enclosed) 
integer = Word( nums ) # simple unsigned integer
arithOp = Word( "+-*/", max=1 ) # arithmetic operators
enclosed << ( nestedParens | arithOp | integer )

data = '( * 1 2 ( - 4 3 ) )' 

print enclosed.parseString(data).asList()
```

output:

```
$ python parse.py 
[['*', '1', '2', ['-', '4', '3']]]
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use a Forward to show that nestedExpr might include like nestedExpr's - that's why it's named *nested*Expr. :) All that is needed is just `expr = nestedExpr('(',')', content=integer|arithOp)` and then use `expr.parseString(data)` on the original string. Otherwise, nice answer, thanks for mentioning pyparsing!

Comment: Also, the OP had asked about doing on-the-fly conversion of ints or floats. Pyparsing allows you to define parse actions that will do this kind of conversion at parse time.  `integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda tokens: int(tokens[0]))` will do this, similar for float.